# How do I iterate through a column, multiplying each value against the value in two other fixed cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to multiply a column with 2 fixed cells using VBA, but it is giving me back the same result, 2800, for the whole range:

```
For q = 4 To 9

  For w = 3 To 8

    Cells(q, 3).Value = Cells(12, 2) * Cells(13, 2) * Cells(w, 2).Value

  Next w

Next q
```

[image]

Comment: remove the inner loop and use `q-1` instead of `w` in the `* Cells(w, 2).Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no wonder.

You have an outer loop q and an inner loop w. 
For all q the calculation is done with w = 8 in the end.

Therefore you write into all cells Cells(q,3)the latest result for w = 8 and that's why all results all the same.

the execution sequence in your code is:

```
q = 4, w = 3
q = 4, w = 4
q = 4, w = 5
...
q = 4, w = 8   > this is the shown result for in Cells(4,3)
q = 5, w = 3
...
q = 5, w = 8   > this is the shown result for in Cells(5,3)
...
q = 9, w = 3
...
q = 9, w = 8   > this is the shown result for in Cells(9,3)
```

What you need is:

```
For w = 3 To 5
    Cells(w+1, 3).Value = Cells(12, 2) * Cells(13, 2) * Cells(w, 2).Value
Next w
```